# I need help solving a summation problem.

Tags: calculus, summation

Ok, so the image below is a scan of my work on this problem, I think I got as far as I could, but don't know how to proceed, or if I have even been doing this correctly thus far.

[image]

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=1}^{n^2} \frac{4^{2k+1}}{7^{-k+4}} = \sum_{k=1}^{n^2}\frac{4}{7^4} (7 \cdot 16)^k\\
&= \frac{4}{7^4} \times 7 \cdot 16 \times \frac{(7 \cdot 16)^{n^2} - 1}{7 \cdot 16 -1}
\end{align*}
Similar computation for the other sum.

Comment: I don't get how you got that. Can you please explain?

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out, just an algebra rule I had forgotten. Thank you! I did the same thing for the other summation and I believe I now have a valid answer.